# Sorted map won't allow removal

Tags: java, dictionary

I searched earlier for a way to sort TreeMaps according to the values, was able to find a function that does that, but now it seems something's wrong with the remove() method, tried various different ways to remove using a key but its not working, and to tell the truth I don't fully understand the sorting function, can someone explain what is the problem?

The Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<String,Integer> theTree = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
    theTree.put("A", 5);
    theTree.put("B", 3);
    theTree.put("F", 1);
    theTree.put("D", 5);
    theTree.put("E", 6);
    theTree.put("C", 7);
    System.out.println(theTree.toString());
    Map<String,Integer> sortedTree = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
    sortedTree = sortByValues(theTree);
    System.out.println(sortedTree.toString());
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedTree.entrySet())
    {
        if(entry.getKey().equals("A"))
            sortedTree.remove(entry.getKey());
    }
    System.out.println(sortedTree.toString());
    theTree = new TreeMap<String,Integer>(sortedTree);
    theTree.remove("B");
    System.out.println(theTree.toString());
}

public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sortByValues(final Map<K, V> map) {
    Comparator<K> valueComparator =  new Comparator<K>() {
        public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
            int compare = map.get(k2).compareTo(map.get(k1));
            if (compare == 0) return 1;
            else return compare;
        }
    };
    Map<K, V> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
    sortedByValues.putAll(map);
    return sortedByValues;
}
```

The Output:

```
{A=5, B=3, C=7, D=5, E=6, F=1}
{C=7, E=6, A=5, D=5, B=3, F=1}
{C=7, E=6, A=5, D=5, B=3, F=1}
{A=5, C=7, D=5, E=6, F=1}
```

The A is still in the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete only via `Iterator` during `map traversal`:

```
Map<String,Integer> sortedTree = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
            System.out.println(sortedTree.toString());
            Iterator<Entry<String,Integer>> itr = sortedTree.entrySet().iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                Entry<String,Integer> entry = itr.next();
                if(entry.getKey().equals("A"))
                    itr.remove();
            }
```

`map.remove` would work fine while not under iteration else removal would throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if iteration is not happening via `Iterator`. That's the case with many other collections too.

This is what I meant as per `TreeMap` javadoc:

> The iterators returned by the iterator method of the collections
>   returned by all of this class's "collection   view methods" are
>   fail-fast: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the
>   iterator is created,   in any way except through the iterator's own
>   remove method, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @ZouZou the explanation on the Comparator answers why remove is failing

Comment: @bjhaid Yes but that was not the initial problem. map traversal was missing in his explanation.

Answer (score 4):

In your Comparator, you are removing any chance of it returning 0 (`if (compare == 0)return 1`) Thus when you go to remove, there is never any chance for your inputted value to equal a value in the Set and nothing will be removed. If there is no particular reason why you are removing the chance for them to be deemed equal, just remove that line from your comparator.

Comment: As I said, I don't fully understand it, but I tried to removed it and returned compare right away, caused some errors, and only printed the theTree

Comment: The comparator determines how items are placed in the Map. Returning < 0 means that k1 < k2, returning 0 means k1 = k2 and returning > 0 means k1 > k2. If you never return 0, when you delete, it will use the comparator and never find k1 = k2, so will never find the item you want to delete, and thus wont delete anything. Also, if you are getting errors, please post them.

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1115)
 at java.util.TreeMap$EntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1151)
 at java.util.TreeMap$EntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1146)"

Comment: @HElwy See harsh s answer above about that.